# JSON string in ajax post request content-type application/formdata vs application/json

Tags: php, ajax, json

It might be a very basic or silly question but its indeed a deep concept question.

If I have a ajax post request like (client side):

```
var response = {};
        response['key'] =  value;
        response['key2'] = value2;

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            data: JSON.stringify(response),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {}
        });
```

And on server side I do

```
$a = json_decode($data, true);
```

And I can $a['abc'] and do rest of my work.

Question is since I have not specified contentType as application/json in ajax request the jquery would send the data as application/form-data which means I should access it via $_POST['data'] and don't do json_decode. Right?

Vise Versa
If I send json string on client side with content type application/json then on server side I can on access it via json_decode and not $_POST[]. Right?

I'm quiet confused on this basic issue. Can anyone provide a good explanation on this???

Note: My server returns the json encoded data in return. And Im using slim framework so I can access the post body as $app->request->getBody();

Comment: Doesn't matter how header is sent, the important thing is to be a clean json_encode/json_decode at the end. In you case, the decode process is made after you GET posted data in a variable. Literally if you work with json, then you have to declare header accordingly

Comment: Means there is not use of contentType then?

Comment: I have done many of my projects with ajax calls and without specifying contentType and setting dataType as html. Is this the correct approach then?

Comment: As long the code is clean, there's no problem. But when you generate json using php file, literally you must declare content type for json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your data to be accessible through a single variable on the server side, you'll want to do something like this:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xyz.php",
        data: {'data', JSON.stringify(response)},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {}
    });
```

PHP:

```
$a = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Comment: then what will be the use of the contentType then. Means I can set any type or no type and access the data in the way I want?

Comment: Perhaps someone else can speak better to what is currently considered "best practice", but typically, you do not need to set the contentType explicity when using $.ajax

Comment: I have read it on the net, if we dont specify any contentType it will use default application/form-data then...

Comment: My understanding is that this won't be a problem.  You can set the content type if you need to do some checking on the server side, but this code should work either way.